# ionic cordova deepllink not triggering subscribe on device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

So basically I have an ionic 3 app with Angular 8 & Cordova. On the browser everything works just fine, the deeplink.route and deeplinks.routeWithNavController works just fine, the error message is displayed saying no match was found.

On android though this is not the case. Nothing is displayed, no message whatsoever. Almost like the subscribe to the deeplinks did not happen on my device.

Tested this with ionic cordova run android.

Here's the code:

```
constructor(
  public events: Events, 
  public kidsDb: Sqlite, 
  public device: Device, 
  public platform: Platform, 
public commandHandler: CommandHandler,
public statusBar: StatusBar, 
  public splashScreen: SplashScreen, 
  private deeplinks: Deeplinks,
  private translate: TranslateService) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.setDeepkLinkRoutes();
        
        this.statusBar.styleDefault();
        this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
}

private setDeepkLinkRoutes() {
  this.deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {
    '/lost-password': LostPasswordPage,
    '/about': LostPasswordPage,
  }).subscribe((match) => {
    this.commandHandler.showAlert('success nav', match);

  }, (nomatch) => {
    this.commandHandler.showAlert('Error nav no match', nomatch);
  });

  this.deeplinks.route({
    '/lost-password': LostPasswordPage,
    '/about': LostPasswordPage,
  }).subscribe(match => {
    this.commandHandler.showAlert('success', match);
  }, nomatch => {
    this.commandHandler.showAlert('Error no match', nomatch);
  });
}
```

my config.xml files has the following configurations:

```
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-deeplinks" spec="^1.0.22">
    <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="myApp" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_SCHEME" value="https" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_HOST" value="my-domain.com" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX" value="/about" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_2_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_3_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_4_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_5_PATH_PREFIX" value="/" />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_2_SCHEME" value=" " />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_2_HOST" value=" " />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_3_SCHEME" value=" " />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_3_HOST" value=" " />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_4_SCHEME" value=" " />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_4_HOST" value=" " />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_5_SCHEME" value=" " />
    <variable name="DEEPLINK_5_HOST" value=" " />
</plugin>
<universal-links>
    <host name="my-domain.com" scheme="https">
        <path url="/about" />
        <path url="/lost-password" />
    </host>
</universal-links>
```

And my package.json has the following dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "8.2.2",
"@angular/compiler": "8.2.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.2",
"@angular/core": "8.2.2",
"@angular/forms": "8.2.2",
"@angular/http": "7.2.15",
"@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.2",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.2",
"@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.29.0",
"@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^5.30.0",
"@ionic-native/call-number": "5.12.0",
"@ionic-native/camera": "^5.12.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "5.12.0",
"@ionic-native/deeplinks": "^5.30.0",
"@ionic-native/device": "5.12.0",
"@ionic-native/network": "^5.12.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.12.0",
"@ionic-native/sqlite": "^5.12.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.12.0",
"@ionic-native/wheel-selector": "^5.12.0",
"@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.4",
"@ionic/cli": "^6.12.3",
"@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "^3.4.0",
"@types/node": "^12.7.2",
"@types/pouchdb": "6.4.0",
"ajv": "^6.10.2",
"at-least-node": "^1.0.0",
"cordova-android": "^7.1.4",
"cordova-browser": "^5.0.4",
"cordova-ios": "^5.1.1",
"cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
"cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-console": "^1.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
"cordova-plugin-ios-permissions": "https://github.com/MBuchalik/cordova-plugin-ios-permissions.git#v1.1.1",
"cordova-plugin-media-capture": "*",
"cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
"cordova-sqlite-storage": "^3.4.1",
"cordova-wheel-selector-plugin": "^1.1.7",
"dd-trace": "^0.14.0",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.8",
"ionic-plugin-deeplinks": "^1.0.22",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
"ionicons": "4.6.2",
"leveldown": "^5.1.1",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"nan": "^2.14.0",
"ng2-filter-pipe": "^0.1.10",
"phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^8.1.0",
"pouchdb": "^7.1.1",
"pouchdb-adapter-cordova-sqlite": "^2.0.6",
"rxjs": "6.5.2",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"typescript-collections": "1.3.2",
"zone.js": "0.10.2"
```

},

```
"cordova": {
"plugins": {
  "cordova-plugin-console": {},
  "cordova-plugin-device": {},
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
  "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
  "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
  "cordova-wheel-selector-plugin": {},
  "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
  "cordova-plugin-camera": {
    "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "App would like to access the camera.",
    "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "App would like to access the library.",
    "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
  },
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
  "cordova-plugin-media-capture": {
    "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "App would like to access the camera.",
    "MICROPHONE_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "App would like to access the microphone.",
    "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "App would like to access the library."
  },
  "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
  "cordova-plugin-ios-permissions": {},
  "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": {
    "URL_SCHEME": "myApp",
    "DEEPLINK_SCHEME": "https",
    "DEEPLINK_HOST": "my-domain.com",
    "ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
    "ANDROID_2_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
    "ANDROID_3_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
    "ANDROID_4_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
    "ANDROID_5_PATH_PREFIX": "/",
    "DEEPLINK_2_SCHEME": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_2_HOST": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_3_SCHEME": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_3_HOST": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_4_SCHEME": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_4_HOST": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_5_SCHEME": " ",
    "DEEPLINK_5_HOST": " "
  },
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
  "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
    "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
  }
},
"platforms": [
  "browser",
  "ios",
  "android"
]
```

}

Any idea of what I'm missing? If I run ionic serve, on the website it does trigger the error handling for the deeplinks twice, with the messages: 'Error nav no match' & 'Error no match'.
Mobile, nothing.

Comment: Also by accessing my-domain.com the app opens correctly. The device asks me if I want to open the link with my app. The only problem, of course, is the deeplink itself that does nothing

Comment: Have you tried remote debugging? You can step trace thru to see where the error is.

Comment: I'm fairly new to cordova + app development, I wasn't aware I could debug the app on my device! Normally I debug on the browser only.
Is there a specific tool for it? Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest reading this part of the documentation. https://ionicframework.com/docs/troubleshooting/debugging

Comment: It's been a while but I only started working again on this project friday!
@E.Maggini thanks a lot for the assist! After being able to debug I found out the problem. Apparently the version of ionic-plugin-deeplinks I was using throws an error because it's expecting an array of routes but receives null for some reason and after googling for that the answer was downgrading the version. It's a common issue when using a version higher than 1.0.19. Thanks for the assist!